# Randomized Demographic Data Frame Sanity Check in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to make a sample data frame of people with their demographic info. I want to make sure that each row of data generated is logical. Specifically, that no row indicating a person under 22 who also has a doctorate degree. How do I make the data frame do a logical check for that? Below is the code I'm currently using. Variable "a" is the number of rows to output, "b" is median age, and "d"  is probability of NA.

```
AgeFn <- function(a,b){
  MedianYr <- b
  Year <- 1900 + as.POSIXlt(Sys.Date())$year
  RNormYr <- as.integer((rnorm(a)*10+MedianYr))
  Age1 <- Year - RNormYr
}

EducationFn <- function(a, d){
  EducationLs <- c("Some High School", "High School Grad", "Associates", "Bachelors",     
  "Masters", "Profession", "Doctorate", NA)
  Education1 <- sample(EducationLs, a, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.085, 0.25, 0.075, 0.176, 0.072,   
  0.019, 0.012, d))
  return(Education1)
}

UserGen <- function(a,b,d){
  ID <- c(1:a)
  Age <- AgeFn(a,b,c)
  Education <- EducationFn(a,d) 
  data.frame(ID, Age, Gender, Education)
}
```

System: Mac OS 10.8.2, RStudio: v0.97.312

Comment: Hi There.  Could you please clarify what is `c` in `Age <- AgeFn(a,b,c)`.    Thanks and welcome to SO

Comment: It would be better if you expanded your EducationFn probabilities to be a function of age. (This is true in real samples.)  It is possible, though improbable, for someone under the age of 22 to get a doctorate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check your data.frame for undesired combinations, you can use commands like:

```
subset(df, Age <= 22 & Education == 'Doctorate')
```

or

```
df[df$Age <= 22 & df$Education == 'Doctorate',]
```

both of which will return any lines in the data frame that match your criteria.

If your intent is to sample from a probability distribution conditional on another established variable, you might try `ifelse`. A verbose example:

```
EduByAge <- function (Age) {
  ifelse(Age < 12 , sample(c('Elementary', 'Middle'), size=1),
    ifelse(Age < 22, sample(c('Elementary', 'Middle', 'High', 'College'), size=1),
           ifelse(Age < 35, sample(c('Elementary','Middle','High','College','Masters','Doctorate'),size=1), 'None')))
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if that string of `ifelse` statements will resolve as expected.   Specifically, the last one has a `yes` argument but no `no` argument.

Comment: I dont think it needs a default.  Your last `ifelse` is simply the _else_ to the previous `ifelse`.